# find repetition cell array

Tags: matlab, cell

I have a cell array like

```
 A = {'hello'; 2; 3; 4; 'hello';2;'hello'}
```

I would like to find if there are repetitions in this array and identify their names and indexes.
In this example I would like to have something like:

```
names = {'hello';2};
indexes = [1, 5, 7;
         2, 6, 0];
```

I've put the last element of the second row of index to 0 just to not have problems in the dimensions...My problem is that the cell array is both char and double...I don't know how to deal with this...

Comment: converting all entries to string is acceptable? what will happen if your `A` was `{'2';2}`?

Comment: yes in my particular case it's possible... I would like to know if exists a general solution though... anyway if you have this solution it is more than welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's messy, but it can be done:

```
m = max(cellfun(@length, A));
A2 = cellfun(@(e) [double(e) inf(1,m-length(e)) ischar(e)], A, 'uni' ,false);
A2 = cell2mat(A2);
[~, ~, jj] = unique(A2,'rows');
num = accumarray(jj,1,[],@numel);
[~, kk] = max(bsxfun(@eq, jj, find(num>1).'));
names = A(kk);
indices = arrayfun(@(n) find(jj==jj(kk(n))), 1:length(kk), 'uni', false);
```

*How this works*: `A2` is just `A` converted to a matrix of numbers. Each row represents one entry of `A`, with the last column used as a flag to distinguish original numbers from original strings, and `inf` used as a filler. Then the usual couple of `unique` and `accumarray` do the actual job, and the results are obtained from `jj` and `num` with some comparisons and indexing.

Comment: Undefined function or variable 'bb'.

you mean kk?

Comment: Although a somewhat clumsy answer (I have a feeling it could be done more easily), here's another example of the power of `unique` and `accumarray` together! :-) @chappjc

Comment: A little bit hard to follow, especially for someone that does not really understand the optimization methods like `bsxfun` and `cellfun` but nevertheless, a valid solution.

Comment: @MZimmerman6 I agree. It's also hard to follow for me a while after I wrote it :-D And as I said above, it's perhaps a clumsy way. I have the feeling that, following this approach, it could be done better; specially the lines after `unique`

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using a structure that contains both strings and numbers things are not quite as easy. Assuming you can not change this at all, the best way to find unique values and their indices is to just loop through the specified cell array, and save its contents to a map object that will store the indices that those unique entries exist.

This is pretty simple with MATLAB's map structure and can follow the code below.

```
A = {'hello'; 2; 3; 4; 'hello';2;'hello'}

cellMap = containers.Map();
for i = 1 : numel(A)
    mapKey = num2str(A{i});
    if cellMap.isKey(mapKey)
       tempCell = cellMap(mapKey);
       tempCell{numel(tempCell)+1} = i;
       cellMap(mapKey) = tempCell;
    else
        tempCell = cell(1);
        tempCell{1} = i;
        cellMap(mapKey) = tempCell;
    end
end
```

With this you can find all unique values by typing `cellMap.keys`, which will return

```
ans = 
    '2'    '3'    '4'    'hello'
```

And then you can use these keys to find out where they occurred in the original array using `cellMap('hello')`.

```
ans = 
    [1]    [5]    [7]
```

Once you have all of this, you can do a little bit of conversion to get back to the original state and get things more into a format that you want.

```
uniqueVals = cellMap.keys;
uniqueIndices = cell(1,numel(uniqueVals));
for i = 1:numel(uniqueVals)
    uniqueIndices{i} = cell2mat(cellMap(uniqueVals{i}));
      numEquiv = str2double(uniqueVals{i});
      if ~isnan(numEquiv)
          uniqueVals{i} = numEquiv;
      end
end
uniqueVals{4}
uniqueIndices{4}
```

which will return:

```
ans =
    hello
ans = 
    1     5     7
```

Another option, and probably much simpler and straight forward, is to just make a copy of your cell array, and convert all of its contents to a string format. This will not really return things in the format you want immediately, but it is a start

```
B = cell(size(A));
for i = 1:numel(A)
    B{i} = num2str(A{i});
end
[C,~,IC] = unique(B)
```

You can then use the returns from `unique` to find indices, but honestly that is all done already with the mapping code I wrote above.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a much more elegant solution (and simpler!):

```
%// Find repeating cells
A = A(:);        %// Make sure it's a column array
ia = 1:numel(A);
tf = sortrows(bsxfun(@(m, n)cellfun(@isequal, A(m), A(n)), ia, ia(:)));
tf = tf(any(diff([zeros(size(ia)); tf]), 2) & sum(tf, 2) > 1, :);

%// Extract corresponding indices and values
indices = arrayfun(@(x){find(tf(x, :))}, 1:size(tf, 1));
names = cellfun(@(x)A(x(1)), indices);
```

This solution should work on any data, not just strings and numbers.

#### Example

If we run this for:

```
A = {'hello'; 2; 3; 4; 'hello'; 2; 'hello'; 4}
```

we get:

```
indices =
     [4   8]
     [2   6]
     [1   5   7]

names = 
    4
    2
    'hello'
```

Comment: It defiintely looks better than my solution. But the `sortwors` line gives me an error (Matlab 2010b): ??? Error using ==> cellfun
All of the input arguments must be of the same size and shape.
Previous inputs had size 1 in dimension 1. Input #3 has size 8.
Error in ==> @(m,n)cellfun(@isequal,A(m),A(n))

Comment: I think sortrows was added in 2012a or b

Comment: @MZimmerman6 I do have `sortrows`, but it gives me that error

Comment: I'll look into that. I tested that on Octave because I didn't have MATLAB at hand.